# How to create a manifest.json file for webpackerlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I'm playing with React_on_rails, and after cloning their example I can't get it to work with webpacker_lite.  When I run the development server I get this error:

```
`WebpackerLite::FileLoader::NotFoundError in Pages#index
   WebpackerLite can't find the manifest file: /FILE PATH/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/public/webpack/development/manifest.json
    Possible causes:
      1. You have not invoked webpack.
      2. You have misconfigured WebpackerLite's config/webpacker_lite.yml file.
      3. Your Webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
`
```

I've installed the webpack-manifest-plugin and added:

```
  var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // ... 
    plugins: [
      new ManifestPlugin()
    ]
};
```

The documentation for webpack-manifest-plugin says this will generate a manifest.json but it dosen't look like it has.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue the other day.

Use `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` to start the server instead of `rails s`

You can checkout how we solved the issue on if-me [here](https://github.com/julianguyen/ifme/issues/627)

We tried a number of things including updates to node, npm and yarn so if the above doesn't work make sure you have updated those packages which rely on this.